# Failing to install Git (exit code 128) on IntelliJ Windows EDIT: SOLVED

Tags: windows, git, intellij-idea

I am trying to install Git on IntelliJ IDEA Community edition and I got bunch of errors. After closing those errors nothing is installed. I tried to google for solutions, but unsuccessful. Maybe anyone have suggestions what to do? I added some screens to show the errors. Thank you in advance.

P.S. I tried to install Git directly to Windows, but same situation happaned. Same errors.

---

EDIT: SOLVED.

Actually for this problem solution I was looking around 4 hours... Feeling so happy to find the right way!

So the thing what I did to solve:
1. Updated my windows to latest.
2. Deleted all applications related to Git.
3. Went to regedit and followed the given instructions which I found by googling:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SYSTEM -> SERVICES -> NULL and there you will find file called Start. Change the existing value to 1.
4. Restart your operation system.
5. Install necessary Git applications.

That was it. Thanks for the answers!

---

[image: Error 1]
[image]
[image]
...

Comment: /dev/null is a Linux directory. Are you sure you're installing the right version of Git? You might be better off finding a Windows installation (like a .msi file) and then just pointing IntelliJ to the path of git.exe instead of going through the IDE itself

Comment: I just download the Git installer for windows from this link: https://git-scm.com/download/win tried few versions of Git, but I got the same errors. :/

Comment: just as an aside: git is a standalone program, not a Intellj-idea add-on, so you don't install it "on" the IDE, you install another program on your operative system. Standard checklist: 1) check git is not already installed on your machine (go type `git --version` in any terminal); 2) check you downloaded the right version of git. For instance, latest is 2.26.2 not 2.24.1.2. Finally, check architecture (32 or 64 bit) and don't pick the thumbdrive version. 3) do you have admin rights on that machine?

Comment: thanks guys for the advices. tried everything and finally succeed. if you intrested how I found the answer, check above. anyway, have a good day gentlemens.

Comment: you should post your answer below as an answer and accept. do not add your answer to the question - it’s not how SO works.